# Nginx crashes when opened by safari

Tags: laravel, ssl, nginx, safari

My reversed proxy server crashes when it is accessed by safari for some reason... It didnt crash for a while but after adding SSL it and modifying a few things on the Laravel website that is proxied, it seems to have stopped functioning. It crashes the whole VM

Config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name abkie.com;
    return 301 https://abkie.com/$uri$is_args$args;
    #location / {
        #proxy_pass http://192.168.1.7:8080/$uri$is_args$args;
        #proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    #}
}
server{
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name abkie.com;
        include snippets/ssl-abkie.com.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
        access_log            /var/log/nginx/testepito.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/testepito.error.log debug;

        location / {
                 error_log /var/log/nginx/testepitos.error.log debug;
                proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
                proxy_pass          http://192.168.1.7:8080;
                proxy_connect_timeout       3600s;
                proxy_send_timeout          3600s;
                proxy_read_timeout      3600s;
                send_timeout                3600s;
                client_max_body_size    0;
                proxy_redirect      http://192.168.1.7:8080 https://abkie.com;

    }
}
```

ssl-abkie.com.conf:

```
ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.abkie.com/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.abkie.com/privkey.pem;
```

ssl-params.conf:

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1; # Requires nginx >= 1.1.0
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off; # Requires nginx >= 1.5.9
ssl_stapling on; # Requires nginx >= 1.3.7
ssl_stapling_verify on; # Requires nginx => 1.3.7
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains;";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
```

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

nginx -v

```
nginx version: nginx/1.10.3
```

Error logs are basicly empty, (litteraly)...
SSL is from lets encrypt

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try getting on latest version of nginx? Because sometimes it could be a old bug and fixed in current version and you don't want to wast time debugging that

Comment: After installing the newest version it still crashed (after 2 days)

Comment: In Safari open the developer menu, go to inspector. Check network tab, right click on the request and use copy as curl. Copy the generated curl in your question

Comment: after restarting the server it doesnt seem to crash.... im speechless :-(

Comment: Keep on using it, you want to see when it crashes and what request came in at that time

Comment: SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1417D102:SSL routines:tls_process_client_hello:unsupported protocol) while SSL handshaking, client:
i get these crit errors, still no clue if this is the cause of the problem, since many of these dont crash the server